# Code::Blocks GDB Cannot Open file Error

Tags: gdb, codeblocks

I use Code::Blocks 12.11 and Cygwin gdb in Windows 8.
I configured the cygwin gdb in code::blocks, when debug, it reports "cannot open file" error. Using gdb in command line is alright.

I found this [discussion](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,12212.0.html)  from web, but I cannot find the registery entry. My guess is that the Debugger plugin cannot pass a right path name to gdb, there is ">>" in prefix of the path, i copied this into editor and it turns out to be two "sub" charaters (1A in ascii).

Here is the error log, the ">>" is added by hand, because when I copied it here, the "sub" charaters don't show.

> ```
> Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.50.20130728-cvs (cygwin-special)
> Child process PID: 21936
> Cannot open file: >>/cygdrive/e/code/test/main.cpp
> At >>/cygdrive/e/code/test/main.cpp:17
> Debugger finished with status 0
> ```

My question is

1.How can I make the gdb work in the Code::Blocks

2.Are the two "sub" charaters normal and why do they appear, how can I remove it.

Comment: I tried it in Windows 7-64, still the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work by doing the following:

I added a String Value under

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Cygnus Solutions\Cygwin\mounts v2

and

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Cygnus Solutions\Cygwin\mounts v2

(none of the folders were there, so I had to create them manually by selecting New->Key)

with the following parameters:

> name: **cygdrive prefix**
>
> value: **/cygdrive**

Comment: thanks very much for your help, I don't know a lot about the registry things, but your answer really solved my problem

Comment: I confirm this is still the fix in Codeblocks 13.12, and the key under HKEY_CURRENT_USER is sufficient.

Comment: What if you are using Ubuntu ?

Comment: Then I would not need cygwin, which is not the point of this question.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: I did this baffling answer but failed. Maybe I did it wrong? It needs a much clearer explanation please.